# Deserialize dynamic JSON key using Gson + Volley

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I have a JSON with dynamic key value. For example:

```
"location_id": {
  "0": 0,
  "1": 1,
  "2404": "Section 9 Shah Alam - 3.085376,101.522716",
  "272": "Bukit Jelutong - 3.103953,101.527704",
  "545": "Giant Shah Alam - 3.084166,101.549152",
  ...
}
```

Usually, what I would do to a fixed key value is to define it in a POJO class, like so:

Json:

```
"location_id": {
  "id" : "hehe",
  "name": "herpderp",
  "location": "Section 9 Shah Alam - 3.085376,101.522716",
  ...
}
```

POJO will look like this:

```
private String id;
private String name;
private String location;
...
```

And by using [GsonRequest](https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673), it will parse the JSON to the POJO.

But, how do I deserialize a JSON that has dynamic key value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Thanks @Mattia for the reply.

I only need to put `Map<String, String>` to get the whole key-value pairs as String.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse manually your JSON if you have dynamic key value.
For example, do a simple request, then in the response callback parse the data.

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final JSONObject response) {
            //get a fake property from response
            String title = response.optString("title");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(final VolleyError error) {
            //handle errors
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //get request headers
        }
    };
```